# Is it possible to trigger Selenium script based on an event every time automatically

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, browser-automation

Is it possible to trigger Selenium script based on an event every time automatically.

My requirement is: I have a from on web app A and fill this form and then clicks on a button. When user clicks on this button then selenium activates and take that forms data from web app A and navigates to another web app B and fill same data on web app B.

Selenium script should be activated automatically when ever user comes on app A and fill data then clicks on a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement **AbstractWebDriverEventListner** present in selenium
[AbstractWebDriverEventListner](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/AbstractWebDriverEventListener.html)

Create a Class Which extends **AbstractWebDriverEventListner** and override the method **afterClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver)**

```
Public class IListener extends AbstractWebDriverEventListner{
 public void afterClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver){
 //script to fill form for App B
```

Now while executing code the test for Application A just call the IListener and register the EventFiringWebDriver and when the submit button will be clicked it will execute the script written under the method.

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
IListener listener=new IListener();
EventFiringWebDriver edriver=new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
listener.register(eDriver);
//Script to fill form A
```

Now when clicked on a on the button which takes the user to the Application B will triggered by the method 
    **afterClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver)**

Comment: I tried this and found that selenium can handle the events generated by selenium only.

My case is:
1. End user whenever fills the form and clicks on button then selenium should be activated.
2. Selenium will be integrated with web app so that whenever user came and perform activity then selenium should be activated to do further work.
3. If multiple users are doing same thing then it is required to activate selenium's multiple instance to do further activity for each user separately.

Is is possible with selenium. I did search but didn't find the solution.

Comment: Hi, any resolution to this member's question? , In case of a parameter being parsed from App A (Web App) to App B (Selenium Script) and invoking or trigger the script in this case App B based on the incoming parameter. ?

Comment: @Amit Rajput - App A may be completely remote from App B, i speak under correction but was this was your design?. Lets say using a message from a queue sent from App A, then App B would receive the message and the script is triggered. I would appreciate someones response. Please see a similar concept - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63484183/can-my-selenium-framework-consume-an-incoming-message.